# Control line ending of Print in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I've read elsewhere that I can prevent print from going to the next line by adding a "," to the end of the statement. However, is there a way to control this conditionally? To sometimes end the line and sometimes not based on variables?

Comment: How about an if else statement with the different results?

Comment: I was considering doing this, but this seems like it would be a poor way to go about it, I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it. I try to avoid copy/paste whenever I can. And this would mean copypasting the same message with and without a comma at the end. @Kishawy

Answer (score 2):

One solution without future imports:

```
print "my line of text",
if print_newline:
    print
```

which is equivalent to:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print("my line of text", end="\n" if print_newline else "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import print_function

print("foo", end="" if no_line_br else None)
```

should get you going. `None` means default value which is `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant way, but it's an option too.

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("must be a string")
sys.stdout.flush()
```